# VBA - how to skip error and null in Union

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you are well.

I'm a beginner in VBA, I have an UDF to sum cells by colour as below and I'm trying to get the function work even if r2 is not filled in.

```
Function SumBycolor(CellColor As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range) 
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In Union(r1, r2)
    If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex And Not IsEmpty(cl) And Not IsError(cl) Then
        cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
    End If
Next cl
SumBycolor = cSum
End Function
```

Currently everything works if r1 and r2 are filled in.  But it doesn't work if only r1 is filled in.

I tried to fix the problem by adding IsEmpty(cl) in the loop without success.
I assume it's because UNION as it is cannot work if r2 is not fill in but I don't know how to skip errors  in Union.

Do you have an idea how to make the UDF works even if r2 is not fill in ?

Many thanks for your help,

EDIT : The final UDF will contain 10 arguments ( r1,r2,r3...r10) and not 2 (r1,r2)

Comment: Works quite well for me when only `r1` contains filled cells. How is it not working for you?

Comment: Hi Big ben, for me the function returns #Value if there is no range/cell for r2.

Comment: Meaning that you are not passing a third argument? I may have misunderstood your question then. In that case `r2` should be an `Optional` argument.

Comment: Did the answer given help you to solve your problem?  If so, please remember to Accept it, by clicking the Tick mark

Answer (score 2):

Change the function to

```
Function SumBycolor(CellColor As Range, r1 As Range, Optional r2 As Range = Nothing) 
    ...
    Dim rSum as Range
    If r2 is Nothing Then
        Set rSum = r1
    Else
        Set rSum = Union(r1, r2)
    End If
    For Each cl In rSum
        ...
    Next
```

**Update**: If you have a variable number of range-parameters, use the following:

```
Function SumBycolor(CellColor As Range, ParamArray ranges() As Variant)
    
    Dim rSum As Range, i As Long
    Set rSum = ranges(0)
    For i = LBound(ranges) + 1 To UBound(ranges)
        Set rSum = Union(rSum, ranges(i))
    Next

    For Each cl In rSum
        ...
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas. It works fine, nevertheless I  forgot to mention but I would like to have 10 optional arguments and I'm not sure if the solution is optimized in this case.Is there a way to loop through the arguments (r1,r2,r3,r4...) and select the ones which are different from nothing and then unionised them ? Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Yilas In that case, it might be better to replace `r2` through `r11` with [a `ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays), instead

Comment: Love how you steer clear off checking for `If rSum Is Nothing then` each time :+); btw you might close above functions by a `End Function` line and declare `cl`.

Comment: It's not ment to be a complete function, just wanted to show syntax and logic of the range handling as parameters

Answer (score 0):

So many thanks [Chronocidal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9290986/chronocidal) for the paramArray solution. I managed to solve my problem due to "Null" value making the Union solution not working and reduced the code from more than 300 lines to some 15.

Edit: [IT goldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807365/it-goldman), I'd like to but can't. We all are not so advanced...
[image]

Next time I won't be so polite, it's sad, some people deserve that we thank them, even a long time after as they helped a lot.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.